# Dovecot, IMAP outlook reports error 0x800CCC0E cannot synchronize subscribed folders

Tags: outlook, dovecot, imap

I have recently some issues with people using my email server.

They have problems with synchronizing folders on outlook, and I can't figure out what to do.

I found somewhere that I could extend a setting for imap connections:

```
mail_max_userip_connections = 20
```

which didn't really help, I was thinking about extending timeout of connection or something, but really can find anything like that.

In Thunderbird it seems to be OK.

here is dovecot -p result:

http://snipt.org/AAig5

if anything could help please let me know what should provide.

Answer (score 2):

RE: "0x800CCC0E cannot synchronize subscribed folders"

Had this happen today. I knew it had to be a client side error as dovecot logs had nothing but good news.

Resolved by doing the following:

1. Close Outlook.
2. Run the SCANPST.EXE utility on the particular imap account PST file in question. (Make a backup as well - trash it after you verify you are synced properly).
3. Open Outlook.

...Fixed (for me at least.)

As a side note, I noticed I could not view my "Sent" items folder before I fixed error. It was the "Sent" folder in my case -> "Outlook cannot display folder" (if clicked/opened).
I can now see/browse the 'Sent' folder properly, too.

To find location of scanpst.exe or the 'inbox repair tool' for all version of Outlook, consult: 
<del>http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272227</del>
EDIT (JAN2017):
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2534513

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem could be but the Dovecot wiki is definitely worth a look.

> Client issues and configuration

Dovecot 1.x
http://wiki1.dovecot.org/Clients

Dovecot 2.x
http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Clients

Comment: have dovecot 2 and there is no workaround for outlook for imap

Comment: Could you describe the problem in a bit more detail? Is there an error message or does the connection times out?

Comment: 0x800CCC0E cannot synchronize subscribed folders

Comment: 0x800CCC0E means the connection to the server failed. Most likely it's a local problem on the client's machine / network. The problem could be anything really. A misconfigured outlook, firewall blocking, antivirus... The list goes on.

Comment: The thing is that this occurs on few different machines.

Comment: is there any max connections for dovecot or something like that? So when there is too many connections at moment, it will deny to connect?

Comment: Did you check the logs if the maximum number of connections are exceeded?

Comment: not sure where I can check that